# refactoring Quartz jobdata

Tags: java, triggers, refactoring, quartz-scheduler

I had to refactor a class like this:

Class Person in package com.core has a reference to Class Address which is in the same package. I had to move Address to a new package com.core.location. This was simple on the java side, however, there are some quartz triggers which have com.core.Person referencing the old com.core.Address class as part of their job data map. It could be anywhere in the Map.

I have tried a few approaches, like writing an adapter which acts like a common ground between 2 java programs that eventually replace the ols class with the new one. What would be the best way to resolve this?

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: Why can't you just update the code to reference the correct package?

Comment: I have refactored the code, there is no problem with that. Quartz stores maps as part of its job data into database. Many of these maps have objects of the old Person class. It could be anywhere in the map.

Comment: Quartz doesn't use a database.  Your application must be persisting them.  I don't think Quartz can help here; you need to purge the old serialized mappings.

Comment: It does. I am using the JDBCStore provided by Quartz. The scheduler is  retrieved from Spring's SchedulerFactoryBean.

Answer (score 1):

You must change data in column qrtz_job_details.job_class_name